# Download multiple pdfs to be shipped to user in a single folder - React/firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, pdf, download, firebase-storage

This is a bit of a process question and not a specific question.

I have an React/Firebase application where the user needs to be able to download multiple pdfs in a single file. The pdfs themselves are not merged together.

Downloading a single pdf from firebase storage isn't too difficult.  But how do I collect those pdfs (returned as blobs) into a single folder and then ship that folder to the user as a singular download?

Is there a library for this?  Am I thinking about this in the wrong way?

Comment: you can merge pdf files using jsPDF and Pdf.js, or zip the files to a compressed file

Answer (score 0):

You will likely want a backend firebase function that can retrieve the individual pdfs, and then you can collate them into a single zip object using https://stuk.github.io/jszip/